# Transaction stuck on minting

Tags: solidity, nft

I am trying to mint 1000 NFTs using smart contract on Rinkeby with hardhat, but when I run mint script after first transaction all stuck. I am using guide from Alchemy (https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/tutorials/how-to-create-an-nft#step-10-write-our-contract)

contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract CD is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() public ERC721("CD", "CRDS") {}

    function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
        public onlyOwner
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

mint script

```
require('dotenv').config();
const API_URL = process.env.API_URL;
const PUBLIC_KEY = process.env.PUBLIC_KEY;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;

const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
const web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(API_URL);

const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/CD.sol/CD.json");
const contractAddress = process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contractAddress);

async function mintNFT(tokenURI, i) {
  console.log("Transaction started for ", i);
  const nonce = '0x' + (await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PUBLIC_KEY) + i).toString(16) 
  console.log("nonce ", nonce)

  //the transaction
  const tx = {
    'from': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'to': contractAddress,
    'nonce': nonce,
    'gas': 9000000,
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 1999999987,
    'data': nftContract.methods.mintNFT(PUBLIC_KEY, tokenURI).encodeABI()
  };

  console.log(tx.data)

  const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, PRIVATE_KEY);
  const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
  
  console.log(`Transaction receipt: ${JSON.stringify(transactionReceipt)}`);
}

async function mint() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        await mintNFT(`<pinata url>/${i}`, i) //json with metadata for each nft
    }
}

mint();
```

result

```
Compilation finished successfully
Transaction started for  0
nonce  0x266
0xeacabe140000000000000000000000005ba40fbde69e04f2ee30d8581eac10a3d645da590000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005268747470733a2f2f676174657761792e70696e6174612e636c6f75642f697066732f516d504d5066546844505831556b573246364a4d66453451756b707477356f6374547846716247477934466464532f300000000000000000000000000000
Transaction receipt: {"blockHash":"0x8ea8e1cbd0aae4a4872e7953c4bff5053f5ade3206def2f7216f0167c55698ab","blockNumber":9723080,"contractAddress":null,"cumulativeGasUsed":768754,"effectiveGasPrice":"0x77359472","from":"0x5ba40fbde69e04f2ee30d8581eac10a3d645da59","gasUsed":245133,"logs":[{"address":"0x0E1B1F72aCBC9C82F1071A95F08c59ae655dcBbe","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x0000000000000000000000005ba40fbde69e04f2ee30d8581eac10a3d645da59","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"],"data":"0x","blockNumber":9723080,"transactionHash":"0xef1ed0c271afb8ddced730fdf7eff812b11693a3aa705eef43ad0ca46dd5e572","transactionIndex":3,"blockHash":"0x8ea8e1cbd0aae4a4872e7953c4bff5053f5ade3206def2f7216f0167c55698ab","logIndex":10,"removed":false,"id":"log_f0219f75"}],"logsBloom":"0x04000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000800000000000000000080000010000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000808000000000400040000000","status":true,"to":"0x0e1b1f72acbc9c82f1071a95f08c59ae655dcbbe","transactionHash":"0xef1ed0c271afb8ddced730fdf7eff812b11693a3aa705eef43ad0ca46dd5e572","transactionIndex":3,"type":"0x2"}
Transaction started for  1
nonce  0x280
0xeacabe140000000000000000000000005ba40fbde69e04f2ee30d8581eac10a3d645da590000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005268747470733a2f2f676174657761792e70696e6174612e636c6f75642f697066732f516d504d5066546844505831556b573246364a4d66453451756b707477356f6374547846716247477934466464532f310000000000000000000000000000
```

And nothing more. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: but the documentation says that it returns Number https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount

Comment: You are correct, my mistake, the first part should still apply: "I'd only query `getTransactionCount` once before the loop then increment the counter inside the loop."